# Range of population variance

Tags: variance, population

I have a set of numbers between 0 and 1, for instance, {0.4, 0.1, 0.0, 0.8}. What are the minimum and maximum values of population variance on such set?

Comment: Consider the cases all 0; all 1; and half 0 and half 1.

Comment: Thanks @NickCox. But it also depends on the number of elements in the set. No? If I have 100 1's and 100 0's or if I have 1000 1's and 1000 0's.

Comment: Not at all. Variance or equivalently SD adjusts for sample or population size. Did you try the calculation?

Comment: Thanks for your response @NickCox. I did and I never obtain a value larger than 1 as population variance (dividing by N not N-1) and I wonder if it is always the case and I never get a value larger than 1.

Comment: Give an example with variance 1.